# Where do CLI tools conventionally store config files?

Tags: python, configuration, etc

I'm working on CLI tool written in python.

There should be default config directory. Very similar to nginx approach:

```
conf_root
   |__main.conf
   |__projects
      |__project1.conf
      |__project2.conf
      |__another_project.conf
```

I'm looking for a conventionally practices to store config CLI config files.

Package root seems to be a bad idea. I'm thinking about `/etc/package_name` but not sure if it's right and how correctly to work with permissions if I need to create new folder at `/etc` and copy default config files?

I going to use `pip` as an installation tool. (`pip install package_name`)

Comment: Look at the [XDG Base Directory Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) i.e. normally under `~/.config/your_unique_application_name/`

Comment: note that this question has three close votes, two of which are for being "primarily opinion-based". I *almost* cast a close vote for that reason, but I think the real question here is, "where do CLI tools conventionally store config files?" which seems more on-topic.

Comment: @strugee, thank for pointing out. I've added changes to the question. Let me know if I can make it more clear.